# Docker - Should I save base image as well, for --cache-from?

Tags: docker, docker-build

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest as builder
RUN touch /builder
FROM alpine:latest as app
RUN touch /app
CMD ["bash"]
```

First build pulls `alpine` and builds `builder`:

```
$ docker build -t builder --cache-from builder --target builder .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:latest as builder
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 961769676411
Step 2/2 : RUN touch /builder
 ---> Running in d142125feb20
Removing intermediate container d142125feb20
 ---> 1adad9638a6c
Successfully built 1adad9638a6c
Successfully tagged builder:latest
```

Second build use pulled `alpine`, built `builder` and builds `app`:

```
$ docker build -t app --cache-from builder --cache-from app --target app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:latest as builder
 ---> 961769676411
Step 2/5 : RUN touch /builder
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1adad9638a6c
Step 3/5 : FROM alpine:latest as app
 ---> 961769676411
Step 4/5 : RUN touch /app
 ---> Running in 702ee875f781
Removing intermediate container 702ee875f781
 ---> d2b010f12ee8
Step 5/5 : CMD ["bash"]
 ---> Running in 6c7a6354b8bf
Removing intermediate container 6c7a6354b8bf
 ---> e375b0b7905e
Successfully built e375b0b7905e
Successfully tagged app:latest
```

Now, I deleted `alpine` locally:

```
$ docker image rm alpine
Untagged: alpine:latest
Untagged: alpine@sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
```

**My expectation was: building with `--cache-from` would be enough.**
But instead `alpine` is being pulled again. And if it was changed it would invalidate my cache.

```
$ docker build -t app --cache-from builder --cache-from app --target app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:latest as builder
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 961769676411
Step 2/5 : RUN touch /builder
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1adad9638a6c
Step 3/5 : FROM alpine:latest as app
 ---> 961769676411
Step 4/5 : RUN touch /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2b010f12ee8
Step 5/5 : CMD ["bash"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e375b0b7905e
Successfully built e375b0b7905e
Successfully tagged app:latest
```

**Questions**:

1. Is that the right behavior? Can I somehow have `builder` as **the** base image, so when building `app` with two `--cache-from` (one for `builder` and one for `app`) it would be sufficient, as my expectation? So no `pull` would be needed to have `alpine` if doesn't exist ?
2. If no (`1.`), is the following better? Instead of using `FROM alpine:latest` use `FROM alpine:3.10` ? or `3.10.2` ? I want to ensure cache when building from a different machine. I don't know which tag is "reliable" so it won't change: i.e. They update `3` when they push `3.10` because `3.10` is part of `3`. Meaning `3.10.2` won't change? unless there would be `3.10.2.2` :/
3. This is an example. I'm using `ubuntu:18.04` as base image, and currently I did not find something like `ubuntu:18.04.3` or something like that. So there's no more specific image to relay on.

Why it bothers me: because I store these images on my docker repository. And due to that I need to store a copy of alpine as well - the one I used to build. Let's say I call it `myalpine`. Then my build would be:

```
$ docker build -t app --cache-from myalpine --cache-from builder --cache-from app --target app .
```

Thanks

Comment: Regarding `3.` - ubuntu is tagging its images as the version name. So ubuntu:18.04 specific version can actually be: `bionic-20210615.1`